# Selenium WebDriver Java locating two different table cells

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table

I'm using Selenium Webdriver in Java. I have a table, and I like to get my hands on the last cell on the first row, and the last cell of last row. I manage to get one of them

```
WebElement table =driver.findElement(By.className("dataTable"));
List <WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
WebElement firstrow= rows.get(0);
WebElement lastrow= rows.get(rivit.size()-1); 
List <WebElement> firstcells = firstrow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
List <WebElement> lastcells = lastcell.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

firstcell.get(6).getText());
```

This is because I'm locating td-tags twice. Any hints how to get both cells nicely? I have no identifiers in my rows or cells.

Comment: It might help to include your actual source here... for example: what is lastcell assigned to? Did you just mean instead `lastcells = lastrow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to make it with cssSelectors:

```
String cssLast="table[class='dataTable']>tr:first-child>td:last-child"
String cssFirst="table[class='dataTable']>tr:last-child>td:last-child"
```

it will be smt like that;

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssLast)).getText();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssFirst)).getText();
```

**another approach is using js:**

```
String getText(cssSel){
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\""+cssSel+"\");");
        stringBuilder.append("return x.text().toString();")       ;


       String res= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
}

text1=getText(cssLast);
text2=getText(csscssFirst);
```

But always make sure that you located elements properly (e.g. using firepath, firebug addon in firefox)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath to get the elements:

```
WebElement lastCellInFirstRow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("table[@class='dataTable']//tr[1]//td[last()]"));
WebElement lastCellInLastRow = driver.findElement(By.xpath("table[@class='dataTable']//tr[last()]//td[last()]"));
```

Here's the [xpath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). You can play with xpath [here](http://ponderer.org/download/xpath/).

Comment: Is there a more specific error message? Could you try again but start the expression with `//table` instead of `table`? I don't use selenium server myself so I can't try.

Answer (score 0):

The TableDriver extension (https://github.com/jkindwall/TableDriver.Java) offers a nice clean way to handle things like this.  If your table has headers, you can (and should) identify the cell column by its header text, but in case you don't have headers, you can still do something like this.

```java
Table table = Table.createWithNoHeaders(driver.findElement(By.className("dataTable")), 0);
WebElement firstRowLastCell = table.findCell(0, table.getColumnCount() - 1);
WebElement lastRowFirstCell = table.findCell(table.getRowCount() - 1, table.getColumnCount() - 1);
```